# SVG Not Rendering in Edge

Tags: svg

This SVG seems to work fine in EVERYTHING apart from Microsoft Edge, surprise surprise.

[Here is a link to the SVG](http://codepen.io/martynball/pen/ZezvBV)

```
<svg version="1.1" class="slider-svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="00%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#e1e1e1;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#212121;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g class="back1">
    <text class="text">Civic Type R</text>
    <text class="text">Civic Type R</text>
  </g>
  <g class="back2">
    <text class="text">Civic Type R</text>
    <text class="text">Civic Type R</text>
  </g>
  <g class="back3">
    <text class="text" >Civic Type R</text>
    <text class="text">Civic Type R</text>
  </g>
  <g>
    <text fill="url(#grad1)" class="text" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10">Civic Type R</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

All I can see in Edge is a thin line at the top, sort of seems like it's 1px in height.

Not too sure what other information I could give you.

Comment: Tried to add the `viewBox` attribute?

Comment: Don't think edge supports CSS transforms on SVG elements yet so the content is probably off the page. Try SVG transform attributes instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple changes you probably want to make.

1. Remove one of the duplicated fill attributes from your last text tag.  You wrote  fill="url(#grad1)" more than once.  Setting the same attribute more than once is invalid XML. Edge mentioned that as an error when I tried opening a .svg file with your content.
2. Add the SVG namespace to your svg tag.  For example, 
   The namespace is important if you want your SVG to render as SVG instead of more general XML markup in Edge.

Comment: This question is over 4 years old...

Comment: That is an accurate statement about the question but my answer is very new and very good.  I found the question while troubleshooting other issues with SVG which means others are seeing it now too.

If you hate your own question just because it is old, that's your problem.  My answer is not the problem.